# xcodebuild tries to build and code sign OS X frameworks when building an iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, command-line, xcodebuild

I'm trying to do a command line build of [Firefox for iOS](https://github.com/mozilla/firefox-ios) using the following `xcodebuild` invocation:

```
xcrun xcodebuild clean archive \
  -derivedDataPath ./DerivedData \
  -archivePath ./$BUILDSCHEME.xcarchive \
  -project Client.xcodeproj \
  -scheme $BUILDSCHEME \
  -sdk iphoneos \
  -skipUnavailableActions || exit 1
```

We have a number of third-party dependencies in the project, and the build is currently failing on [SWXMLHash](https://github.com/drmohundro/SWXMLHash) with the following issue:

```
=== BUILD TARGET SWXMLHashOSX OF PROJECT SWXMLHash WITH THE
    DEFAULT CONFIGURATION (Release) ===

Check dependencies
CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type
    'Framework' in SDK 'iOS 9.0'

** ARCHIVE FAILED **
```

SWXMLHash is a framework that has both an OS X and an iOS target in its project. As you can see it it trying to build `SWXMLHashOSX`.

We are obviously only interested in the iOS version.

This also happened for another dependency and to resolve that we actually forked it and removed the OS X targets from it, so that it was a pure iOS project.

But I don't think that is really a solution and I would like to understand why this is happening.

Is there a way to make xcodebuild not build OS X targets?

Comment: Does it use the right version of the framework when you build from the Xcode application (UI)?

Comment: Yup. No problem from Xcode builds.